# How to fix deleteOne() function of a mongoose model when it does not delete by req.params.id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Firstly to be mentioned, I'm absolutely new to Node.Js and MongoDB.

I'm coding a back end API with Node.Js and MongoDB which will deal with GET, POST, DELETE requests from the front end, quite simple stuff.

I'm stuck while working with DELETE functionality.

Here is my **posts.service.ts** file contains this **deletePost()** function which sends the postId to the back end **app.js** file.

`

```
deletePost(postId: string) {
    this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/posts/' + postId)
    .subscribe(() => {
      console.log(postId);
      console.log('Deleted');
    });
  }
```

`

I have added this **console.log(postId)** to check whether it is actually containing the actual postId and found that it does. I have also matched it with the real Id in MongoDB by checking through mongo shell.

Here is the **delete()** function in the back end **app.js** file that should do the actual task.

`

```
app.delete("/api/posts/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  Post.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    res.status(200).json({message: "Post deleted"});
  });
});
```

`

The **console.log(result)** line should print some result in the terminal, but it does not, so does not it delete the collection in the DB.

I`m running this on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS pc.

Some clue would mean great help. Thank you very much for your kind effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deleteOne` doesn't return the deleted document. It always deletes the first matching document and return the number of documents deleted with the boolean value.

From the mongodb [**docs**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/#db.collection.deleteOne) deleteOne:

> Returns:
>
> 1. A document containing: A boolean acknowledged as true if the operation ran with write concern or false if write concern was
>      disabled
> 2. deletedCount containing the number of deleted documents

From the mongoose [**docs**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteOne)

> Deletes the first document that matches conditions from the
>   collection. Behaves like remove(), but deletes at most one document
>   regardless of the single option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir. But in my case should not it delete the collection as I'm passing the Id of that collection, should not it delete when it finds matched Id ? Because that specific collection is remaining still in the DB, not getting deleted.

Comment: It should. Check the console for `req.params.id` and for `result`. And please let me know.

Comment: Just checked now. None of the `console.log()` statements from the **app.js** file print anything in the console. Only the `console.log()` statements from the **posts.service.ts** work which print the actual postId. It seems there is a problem the postId reaching to the **app.js** file.

Comment: Thank you sir for your effort and the clue, it will help finding the actual flaw.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly the same, i solved returning the deleteOne promise object and then using the .then property of the promise. 
Something like this:

Model.js

```
...
bicicleSchema.statics.deleteById= function(id, cb){
    return this.deleteOne({code: id}, cb);
};
...
module.exports = mongoose.model('Bicicle', bicicleSchema);
```

Service.js

```
var Bicicle = require('../../../model/bicicle');
...
const id = req.params.id;
Bicicle.deleteById(id).then(()=>{
    //your code
});
...
```